# if else condition for floating numbers in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to replace values with Nan if it is smaller than the threshold.

```
D=290.93
if [ $(echo "$D">=5.0 | bc)  ]; then Dd=$d; else Dd=nan; fi
echo $Dd
```

This only gives nan values in the results irrespective to reference value $D.

```
D=290.93
if [ $(echo "$D>=5.0" | bc)  ]; then Dd=$d; else Dd=nan; fi
echo $Dd
```

This do not replace the values but it gives me a same value as D.
please point out a mistake or suggest me any other way to complete the objective.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, your test is backwards. You will only set `nan` if `$D >= 5.0`. Better `if [ $(echo "$D>=5.0" | bc)  -eq 1 ]; then Dd=$d; else Dd=nan; fi`

Comment: Start from the inside out and look at what happens if you try to run `echo "$D">=5.0 | bc` on the command line – you'll create a file called `=5.0` because the unquoted `>` is interpreted as an output redirection.

Comment: `[ 0 ]` will return 0.  `[ 1 ]` will also return 0.  So `if [ 0 ]; then` and `if [ 1 ]; then` will always execute the first set of commands.  Because `[ 0 ]` and `[ 1 ]` are testing if the strings `0` and `1` are empty.  They aren't.

Comment: Thank you, David C. Rankin. This works perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, you can use the arithmetic condition for this kind of tests:

```sh
if (($(bc <<< "$D >= 5.0"))); then
```

The output of a comparison in `bc` is `1` if for true and `0` for false; within `(( ))`, `1` returns a successful exit status and `0` an unsuccessful status.

---

Your test is doing a few things wrong:

- `echo "$D">=5.0 | bc` creates a file `=5.0` because the redirection `>` is unquoted
- your test effectively becomes `[ $(echo '' | bc) ]`, which in turn is `[ ]`, which is always false

A solution closer to what you attempted:

```sh
if [ "$(echo "$D >= 5.0" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
```

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin, but this does not work for me this gives "Syntax error: redirection unexpected"

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel Are you using Bash or call your script with sh?

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel That's an error from the `dash` shell, not `bash`. On recent versions of Ubuntu and Debian (and their relatives), /bin/sh is `dash` rather than `bash`, so if you want to use `bash` features (like here-strings with `<<<`), you need to explicitly specify bash. Use a shebang line of either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and don't override that by running the script with the `sh` command.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can use something like:

```
D="290.93"
echo|awk -v d=$D '{if (d>=5) print d; else print "nan"}'
```